# Show or hide a React component rendered from an array, only a specific one

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am rendering some elements from an array. For each of these elements a component should be rendered if and only if a value in state is true.
so it is like this:

```
element.map(item => {
   <div>{item.name}</div>
   { state.property && <MyComponent /> }
})
```

The problem is, this component should be rendered when I hover the mouse over the `<div>` element. But when I hover and the state.property value gets true, all these components are shown. Not just the specific one.

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: a Tip: if you are mapping over an array you will need to have a unique key for each of the items.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the hovered div to show, then the best solution would probably be better to have a separate component altogether. Inside that component have a new state that changes on hover

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent"

function HoveredComponent (itemName) {
    const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);

    return ( <> // remember JSX needs to be all within a node
        <div
            onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}
        >{itemName}</div>
        { hovered && <MyComponent/> }
    </>)
}

export default function App () {
    var element = [];
    return (
        element.map(item => <HoveredComponent name={item.name}/>)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your answer. What I have done finally is:
For `<MyComponent />` I added a class to set its display to none or block.
Then inside the array `element` I have a field which can be whether true or false.
The `onMouseOver` event will pass the index of that element, accordingly the component class will be assigned for that particular element.
Hope it helps others.